# Flutter retrofit with query segment

Tags: flutter, retrofit

Want to call API with retrofit in flutter.
My API request is like that

[http://192.168.1.10:9883/Exampleprint?type=IMAGE&data="s"&width=100&height=100&blanklines=0&offset=120](http://192.168.1.10:9883/Exapm;eprint?type=IMAGE&data=%22s%22&width=100&height=100&blanklines=0&offset=120)

in my project, I do like that

```
@GET('$ENDPOINT_PRINT?type={type}&data={data}&width={width}&height={height}&blanklines={blanklines}&offset={offset}')
@FormUrlEncoded()
Future<PrintScanResponse> print(
  @Part(name: 'type') String type,
      @Part(name: 'data') String data,
      @Part(name: 'offset') int offset,
      @Part(name: 'width') int width,
      @Part(name: 'height') int height,
      @Part(name: 'blanklines') int blankLines,
);
```

But I can't fetch that API.
How can I do with retrofit?
I am very confusing with retrofit annotation.

Comment: Use flutter default http lib instead.

Comment: No... I only want to do this with, cause do with other.